# SQL Cannot Format Numbers and Decimal (Always Automatically Rounding Up)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to confirm if SQL still can do format numbers from 123456.68 to 123,456.68
like this
[Query from https://www.mssqltips.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/874MV.png)

```
    SELECT FORMAT(1234.5678, 'N', 'en-us')
```

since my SQL always rounded it like this [my MySQL query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCe2K.png)

I tried several query I found on other stack overflow like

```
SELECT FORMAT(1234.56,'#,0.0000')
```

and

```
SELECT Format(1234.56,'#,##0')
```

then

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456.789, '###,###,###.##', 'en-us')
```

But it still rounded the decimal...
Is it will always rounded the decimal or there's some setting I need to do?
Is there any way to do it ? I am using mySQL. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply:

```
SELECT FORMAT(123456.68,2);
```

> Parameters : This function generally accepts three parameters.
>
> N – The number which is to be formatted.
>
> D – The number of decimal
> places to which the number is round off.
>
> locale – It’s an optional
> parameter, which decides a thousand separators and grouping between
> separators. By default, en_US locale is present in MySQL.
>
> Returns :
> The function formats the given number, round off it to a certain
> decimal place, and return the number in the form of string.

Check for more info: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/format-function-in-mysql/

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4aa3cbf11cc05f2e1accc4fa6bcd20a1